# How to push html button value attribute into the array on js?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

How can i push the value of my button into the array in JS? I already have a code but it keeps pushing the btn1 value but not the btn2

```
<button id="btn1" value="btn1" onclick="clicked()">BTN1</button>
    <button id="btn2" value="btn2" onclick="clicked()">BTN2</button
```

> 

**JS**

````
function clicked(){
  
  
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
  
  var newBtn = btn.value;
  
  arraySelected.push(newBtn);
  
  console.log(arraySelected);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Take the value of the target of the event and push it into the array

```js
const arraySelected = [];
function clicked(e) {
  const newBtn = e.target.value;
  
  arraySelected.push(newBtn);
  
  console.log(arraySelected);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" value="btn1" onclick="clicked(event)">BTN1</button>
<button id="btn2" value="btn2" onclick="clicked(event)">BTN2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're always selecting the value of the first button.

```
getElementById('btn1')
```

Generally, with more modern JS, instead of inline code in the HTML, we use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get the buttons and attach listeners to them as I've done in this example...

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
});

const arraySelected = [];

function handleClick(e) {
  const { value } = e.target;
  arraySelected.push(value);
  console.log(arraySelected);
}
```

```html
<button value="btn1">BTN1</button>
<button value="btn2">BTN2</button>
```

...or you can use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) on a parent component so you're only using one listener to catch the click events from child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');

buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

const arraySelected = [];

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    arraySelected.push(value);
    console.log(arraySelected);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button value="btn1">BTN1</button>
  <button value="btn2">BTN2</button>
</div>
```